# Backbone collection trigger twice when going back

Tags: backbone.js, triggers, marionette, backbone.js-collections

I have a weard issue with a collection, when I first load my compositeView everything is working great but then when I start navigate in my app and then comeback to my compositeView(Backbone.history.navigate) it looks like my collection is called twice (my itemviews are fired twice).

I have try to debug, but I fetch my collection only once, the is only one init, the router seems to be ok too.

Here is my compositeView:

```
'use strict';
define(["jquery", "backbone", "marionette", "text!templates/portraits/portrait.html", "view/portraits/portraitItemView", "collection/portraitCollection", "application", "JSMovieclip"], function($, Backbone, Marionette, template, PortraitItemView, portraitCollection, App) {
var PortraitsCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : _.template(template),
    collection : portraitCollection,
    tagName: "div",
    id : "articles",
    itemView : PortraitItemView,
    itemViewContainer : '#list-articles',
    itemViewOptions: {
      collection: portraitCollection
    },
    initialize : function (options) {

        _.bindAll(this);
        this.options = options || {};
        this.collection.fetch({
          type: 'POST',
          success : function(data, raw) {
            App.execute('loader', false);
          }
        });
    },
```

And here is my collection :

```
'use strict';
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "marionette", "model/portraitsModel"], function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, PortraitModel) {
    var PortraitCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : PortraitModel,
        sync: function(method, model, options) {

          var params = _.extend({
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              url: 'http://backend.url.fr/api/portraits/get_list/',
              processData: false
          }, options);

          return $.ajax(params);
        },
        parse : function(response) {
            this.totalLength = response.count;
            return response.portraits;
        }
    });
    return new PortraitCollection;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it looks like my collection is called twice (my itemviews are fired twice)."  Please explain in a little more detail, I don't see anywhere in this code where itemView is called at all.  And do you mean that the collection is only fetched one time each time you route to something that initializes PortraitsCompositeView, or it is just fetched the first time you go there?  The code in your router would be helpful.

Comment: Did you intended making PortraitCollection a singleton? The decision to return a new PortraitCollection instead of returning the 'Class' is a "bad smell"!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my error, my json was returning an empty "id" field, after fixing it, everything works great.

Comment: I have the same problem, there is no empty Id, still request twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection fetch is appending the items to itself.

You can add `reset:true` to your Collection.fetch properties

```
initialize : function (options) {

    _.bindAll(this);
    this.options = options || {};
    this.collection.fetch({
      reset: true,
      type: 'POST',
      success : function(data, raw) {
        App.execute('loader', false);
      }
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already try this solution without any change. (I added my collection in my first messageà.